# Unable to query using Hive Serde?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I have created the hive table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE tableex11(id STRING , name STRING)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "input.regex" =
    "(.*)&&(.*)"
    )
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION '/user/myusername';
```

When I do

```
select * from tableex11;
    1   gg
    2   abishek
    3   murali
    But when i Query for a  columns like below
    select id from tableex11;
    select id,name from tableex11;
```

I get the following error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doA
```

Comment: That is not the right exception. Look at the whole exception chain (the `Caused by:` all the way to the end) there you'll find the original exception.